# Sorting Table by points and dates

Tags: php, sql, sorting

Below is the replica of my table. As you can see below, the row is order by id and date.

```
id     |        date         |    points   
1          Jan 1, 2014             110
2          Feb 12, 2014            20
3          Mar 23, 2014            40
4          Apr 10, 2014            80
5          May 20, 2014            30
6          June 3, 2014            60
7          Jan 15, 2014            10
8          Mar 5, 2014             70
9          Feb 8, 2014             50
10         June 10, 2014            5
```

My goal is to order the row by points that is between 50 to 10 (From Highest to lowest) AND is also CLOSEST to the present date. How can I achieve this?

All rows must be included as a final result

Comment: Can you provide what the result should look like, it is not clear to whether you want rows that lie outside of 10-50, and if so how these should be sorted

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (points >= 10 AND points <= 50) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS order_points     
    FROM points
ORDER BY
    order_points DESC, 
    CASE 
        WHEN order_points = 1 THEN points
    END DESC,  DATEDIFF( date, NOW() )
```

Comment: Like I said "All rows must be included as a final result". This will exclude some of the rows

Comment: If you want points between 50 and 10, you will not have all your rows, or I don't understand ?

Comment: I just want any rows that is between 50-10 AND is closest in present date to be at the top, the other rows will be shifted to the bottom of the rows..

Answer (score 0):

A bit of guessing:

```
select a_date,points 
from t 
order by case when points between 10 and 50 then -1 else 1 end * points
   , abs(DATEDIFF( a_date, now()));
```

For a subset of your data:

```
+------------+--------+
| a_date     | points |
+------------+--------+
| 2014-03-23 |     40 |
| 2014-02-12 |     20 |
| 2014-06-10 |      5 |
| 2014-04-10 |     80 |
| 2014-01-01 |    110 |
+------------+--------+
```

Comment: It is not working, error says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by case when points between 10 and 50 then -1 else 1 end * points' at line 10

Comment: If it is mysql why did you not tag it like that? Now I guessed that anyhow and tested it with `5.5.37-MariaDB`. What version are you using?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle. The case part is kinda not making any sense

Comment: Yes I can, but I think it is better if you do so. Create a fiddle with the table and the data and I will fill in the query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
order by CASE WHEN Points BETWEEN 10 AND 50 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, TheDate desc;

ID  TheDate    Points
--  ---------  ------
 5  20-MAY-14      30
 3  23-MAR-14      40
 2  12-FEB-14      20
 9  08-FEB-14      50
 7  15-JAN-14      10
10  10-JUN-14       5
 6  03-JUN-14      60
 4  10-APR-14      80
 8  05-MAR-14      70
 1  01-JAN-14     110
```